# How to properly draw and update (special) raw image data on canvas without duplication of data ? (html5)

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I don't think the title is very accurate but I can't think of any better.

I'm working with medical images, in these kind of images there isn't definitive pixels values, you have to extract some information and calculate yourself every pixel value. A second particularity is that image resolution can be very huge.

So once I loaded the image into memory I have an ArrayBuffer and some other attributes needed for calculation. Since these images aren't based on any common format I can't use image DOMElement to draw them on a canvas.

Here the 2 related issue I have :

1) I have to use ImageData to draw my image into a canvas, this means I have to iterate over my ArrayBuffer calculate each pixel value and stored them on an ImageData, then I use canvas.putImageData() and the browser will probably iterate over again the ImageData and display pixels. I don't like this because it needs to iterate twice in order to display the image and that every time it's update.

2) As I said images can be very huge so I need to use scaling/slicing, but canvas only provides these features for drawImage not for putImageData. If I don't want to calculate it myself I have to use a buffer canvas, copy the entire image in it and then use drawImage with this buffer canvas as image. 
This is bad for 2 reasons :

- I'm duplicating data, I have to keep the original ArrayBuffer and a buffer canvas. The buffer canvas can be created and deleted but as I need to update the image on the mouse movement it's better to keep it.
- If a change is made on the image like the contrast/brightness I have to re-calculate it for the entire image (buffer canvas creation) even if I'm just displaying a small part of it.

Here is some code :

```
//image contains raw data: TypedArrayView and some attributes
// size (2828,2320)
var image;
//displayed canvas
// size (500,500)
var canvas;
//buffer canvas
// size (2828,2320)
var buffCanvas;

function drawImage(sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight){
   var buffContext = buffCanvas.getContext('2d');
   var imageData = buffContext.getImageData(buffCanvas.width,buffCanvas.height);

   //Iterate over all the image (2828,2320)
   for(var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i++ )
     //process pixel calculation
     imageData[i] = image.buffer[i] + SomeCalculation;

   buffContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

   canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(buffCanvas,sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
}

function onmousemove(){
   //change some image properties
   image.contrast = 150;
   ...

   drawImage(sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
}
```

I'm kinda new on this so I must be missing something because the way I'm doing this can't be productive.

My dream would be to create a view like it's done for ArrayBuffer or to override(not possible) bracket operator or create a fake image element. This could work this way :

```
function MedicalImage(data, ...){
  ...
}

MedicalImage.prototype.getPixelValueAt = function(pos){
  return data[pos] + SomeCalculation;
}

var img = new MedicalImage();
context.drawImage(img,sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

And browser would call getPixelValueAt() to get the pixel value when needed.

Comment: You should look into WebGL. Web based GPU processing. I think this is a perfect application for it. It may not solve the issue posted here, but it will (potentially) speed up the process dramatically. Basically, it will allow you to calculate each new pixel at exactly the same time. I know this isn't quite what you were looking for, but it may help.